# I get an error while running requests_html render function in django enviroment

Tags: python, django, python-requests-html

I highlighted that it happens in django enviroment,because when I run similar scripts with this function outside of django server it works fine.
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
page = session.get('https://python.org/')
page.html.render()
```

but when I run this code through django server, I get something like this(actual error is very long, so I cut all irrelevant pieces)

```
There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
...
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/sogo-sakata/papi/seoparser/schema.py", line 28, in titles
    result = analize(url)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/sogo-sakata/papi/seoparser/utilities.py", line 91, in analize
    page.html.render()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 727, in browser
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
Stack (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 930, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 178, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 201, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 76, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

so I wonder if there is any specific reason why I get this error while running django server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/155#issuecomment-599551052 - found solution for the problem here.